# Postgres insert / delete trigger

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I am wondering if it is possible to create a trigger that will insert or delete a record in my tbl_media table that is in my sde schema (sde.tbl_media) based on an insert or delete in my tbl_media table that is in my public schema (public.tbl_media)?

The reason I have to do this is long, but in short, I can't have a link to a table that is in the public schema in ArcGIS.  I need to keep that table active, since it is receiving input online...so I basically need to create an active copy so I can link to it in the ArcGIS software.

Comment: Yes, tables (or rather any object) of an another schema as the trigger function or the table the trigger is in can be accessed in the trigger. But instead of copying data around, consider a view.

Comment: That is a very good point!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read this: [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)

Comment: Sticky bit - the data in a view isn't editable on the ArcGIS side, though. Which I would need it to be, so this option isn't possible. –

Comment: 1) configure your DB so that you can edit your public table 2) don't put data in the SDE schema 3) you can have `instead of` triggers but 4) don't duplicate/edit/fail to reconcile data unnecessarily. You have a very simple user privilege issue and it is wrong to attempt to rewrite half of the system as a workaround.